# how to use set timeout in v-for loop in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, settimeout, v-for

I want to show every character in a paragraph with a targeted time interval. I think setTimeout() function is best option. But I can't find any way to use. Now how set time interval the v-for loop?
The HTML part:

```
<button @click="showCharacterArray">click me</button>
<p>
   <span v-for="char in characterArray " :key="char">{{char}}</span>
</p>
```

The VUE part:

```
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          Paragraph: "Includes The Plan, The Thought Process, Action, And
                  Implementation. Planning Gives More Power Over The Future.
                  Planning Is Deciding In Advance What To Do, How To Do It, When To
                  Do It, And Who Should Do It. This Bridges The Gap From Where The
                  Organization Is To Where It Wants To Be.",
          characterArray : [],
        }
      },
    
    methods: {
          showCharacterArray() {
          this.CharacterArray = this.Paragraph.split('');
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)?

```js
<script setup>
import {ref, computed} from 'vue'
const Paragraph = "Includes The Plan, The Thought Process, Action, And Implementation. Planning Gives More Power Over The Future. Planning Is Deciding In Advance What To Do, How To Do It, When To Do It, And Who Should Do It. This Bridges The Gap From Where The Organization Is To Where It Wants To Be."
const count = ref(0)
const characterArray = computed(()=>Paragraph.slice(0,count.value).split(''))
const startTimer = () => setInterval(() => count.value++ ,100)
</script>

<template>
<button @click="startTimer">click me</button>
  count: {{count}}
<p>
   <span v-for="char in characterArray" :key="char">{{char}}</span>
</p>
</template>
```

Note: this counter never stops. You should find a way to stop it.